# Removing picture at editing page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm trying to remove the pictures uploaded but it only refresh the page, seems like it could't find the correct picture id in terminal, how can I fix it?

This is terminal after I click "remove picture"

```
17:49:54 web.1  | Started DELETE "/products/9/pictures/9" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-06-19 17:49:54 +0800
17:49:54 web.1  | Processing by Products::PicturesController#destroy as TURBO_STREAM
17:49:54 web.1  |   Parameters: {"product_id"=>"9", "id"=>"9"}
17:49:54 web.1  | Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 695)
17:49:54 web.1  |
17:49:54 web.1  |
17:49:54 web.1  |
17:49:54 web.1  | ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Product without an ID):
17:49:54 web.1  |
17:49:54 web.1  | app/controllers/products/pictures_controller.rb:12:in `set_product'
17:49:54 web.1  | Started GET "/products/9/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-06-19 17:49:54 +0800
17:49:54 web.1  | Processing by ProductsController#edit as HTML
17:49:54 web.1  |   Parameters: {"id"=>"9"}
17:49:54 web.1  |   Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
17:49:54 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:65:in `set_product'
17:49:54 web.1  |   Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
17:49:54 web.1  |   Rendering products/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
17:49:54 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Attachment Exists? (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 9], ["record_type", "Product"], ["name", "pictures"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
17:49:54 web.1  |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.erb:27
17:49:54 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ?  [["record_id", 9], ["record_type", "Product"], ["name", "pictures"]]
17:49:54 web.1  |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.erb:28
17:49:54 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 128], ["LIMIT", 1]]
17:49:54 web.1  |   ↳ app/models/product.rb:7:in `picture_as_thumbnail'
17:49:54 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::VariantRecord Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "active_storage_variant_records".* FROM "active_storage_variant_records" WHERE "active_storage_variant_records"."blob_id" = ? AND "active_storage_variant_records"."variation_digest" = ? LIMIT ?  [["blob_id", 128], ["variation_digest", "6x8KFtM/8O22vFlQ4EVqBuGjN8Q="], ["LIMIT", 1]]
17:49:54 web.1  |   ↳ app/models/product.rb:8:in `picture_as_thumbnail'
```

This is my routes

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'products#home'
  resources :products do 
    resources :pictures, only: [:destroy], module: :products
  end
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
end
```

This is the controller

```rb
class Products::PicturesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product

  def destroy
    @product.picture.purge_later
    redirect_to edit_product_path(@product)
  end

  private

  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:products_id])
  end
end
```

This is the _form.html.erb in edit page

```rb
<div>
    <%= form.label :pictures %>
    <%= form.file_field :pictures, multiple: true %>
    <% if @product.pictures.attached? %>
      <% @product.pictures.each do |picture| %>
        <%= link_to image_tag(product.picture_as_thumbnail(picture)), picture %>
        <%= link_to "remove picture", product_picture_path(product), data: { turbo_method: :delete} %>
        <%= form.hidden_field :pictures, multiple: true, value: picture.signed_id %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you used `params[:products_id]` instead of `params[:product_id]`

If pictures are attachments of products like this

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :pictures
end
```

you can define controller for this purpose to delete any attachment you want

```rb
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # ...
  resources :attachments, only: :destroy
  # ...
end

# app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb
class AttachmentsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    attachment = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:id])
    attachment.purge
    redirect_back fallback_location: root_path, status: :see_other
  end
end
```

And render button to remove picture such way in view

```
<% @product.pictures.each do |picture| %>
  <%= button_to 'Destroy picture', picture, method: :delete, form: { data: { turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?' } } %>
<% end %>
```

Such way you can destroy any attachment in your app, not only pictures and not only in products

Comment: I use ```params[:product_id]``` but got error like ```undefined method `picture' for #<Product id: 9, name: " 123", description: "165494", created_at: "2023-06-17 07:34:13.032402000 +0000", updated_at: "2023-06-20 04:26:42.655241000 +0000">
Did you mean?
pictures```. So I use ```pictures``` instead. However, If I click ```remove``` all the images are remove not the one I want to remove.

Comment: I tried the new way from your answer, but still only refreshing the page and no pictures are removed. Did I di anything wrong here?
These are current routes and controller
[class Products::AttachmentsController < ApplicationController

  def destroy
    attachment = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:id])
    attachment.purge
    redirect_back fallback_location: root_path, status: :see_other  
  end

end]



[Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'products#home'
  resources :products do 
    resources :attachments, only: :destroy, module: :products
  end]

Comment: Do I need to put attachments nested in products or seperate them which means attachments is a isolate resources?

Comment: wondering why not use nested routes?

Comment: Because the pictures belongs to different products?